# How to use Prestashop Customer website field for cc email

Tags: prestashop

Some customers require order emails to be sent for one more recipient (ie. accounting). So, as customer website field not used in shop, planned to use this. However, have trouble for getting data for classes/Mail.php

```
$website = Context::getContext()->customer->website;
```

does not get the data stored in customer website field. How to get this data from customer table website field correctly?
PS 1.7.8.7

All the rest seems doable, just set the value for cc field and it works.

Comment: I would prefer to add a custom field instead of using `website`. It's quite simple.

Comment: It would be problematic with constant updates Prestashop has. There are two good choices. First is minimal change required.  As I have Mail.php overridden anyway, this is OK for me. Second is you make proper module. With all the options to send different mails to logistics , accounting etc. As not so many replies here, the module would have little use probably.

Comment: You can add a custom field to customers without touching PrestaShop code, avoiding problematic situations on updates. I did it several times, just using **override** and other capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

So, found some solution. Not the nice one, as there will be extra query to DB, but it works.

```
$website = Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT `website` FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'customer` WHERE `email` = \''.($to).'\' ');
```